# Question about "as clause"

Tags: grammar

Could you please tell me which of the following sentences use "as" correctly?

1. Her advice is that electrical lights can be used, **as they are done** in art museums, to ensure a stable light level.
2. Her advice is that electrical lights can be used, **as are done** in art museums, to ensure a stable light level.
3. Her advice is that electrical lights can be used, **as done** in art museums, to ensure a stable light level.

Could you please tell me a general rule for such cases, in particular, for reduction form and verb from: **as ... as+clause** , **as + clause**.

4.She would recommend using electrical light **as doing** in art museums to ensure a stable light level.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use any of those constructions.

> Her advice is that electric lights can be used, **as they are** in art museums...

(*As they are* is understood to mean *as they are used*.)

You could also say

> ...electric lights can be used, as is done in art museums...

meaning *as the function of lighting is carried out.*

Comment: How about 4, is it grammatical? can you tell me about verb tense after as?

Comment: I included No. 4 when I said I wouldn't use any of them. If you are using someone's current practice as a comparison (how they do it now), use the present tense after _as_.

Comment: in the 4th sentence, can I use "as they are done"? since the "use" in the sentence is not passive? or do I still have to use "as they are"?

Comment: What would 'they' refer to? You could say "She would recommend using electric light, as art museums do."

Comment: I would like to refer "they" to "electric lights".

Comment: In the first 3, _electric lights_ is the subject of the clause describing the recommendation, so you can refer to them as _they_. In No. 4, the recommendation is _[somebody] using electric light(s)_, so it would have to be followed by _as art museums do [use them]_. I hope I've explained this clearly.